# I want to call a method which is written in program automatically when any form loads

Tags: c#, winforms

please help me to find a solution for calling a method automatically when ever a form is loaded. I want to write a piece of code in every form for invoking a license validation for each form. To avoid I placed that code in the program.cs as a static method and now I want to call the method without re writing my form's codes. Please help me on this issue.

Comment: This might help you if you are talking about windows forms http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172766(vs.80).aspx

Comment: How about calling it from the Form.Load() event?

Comment: i know i am off track why don't you authorize users using web config ?Or is it possible to validate licence on PreInit event ?

Answer (score 5):

Create base class `LicensedForm` which will provide this functionality:

```
public class LicensedForm : Form
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        // invoking a license validation here
        base.OnLoad(e);            
    }
}
```

Inherit other forms from this base class instead of `Form`

```
public class MainForm : LicensedForm
{
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need your forms to handle the `Load` event. Then run your license-check method in the eventhandlers.

You need to make sure that your method is both `public` and `static`, to be able to access it.

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Program.CheckLicense();
}
```